# magento 2 category and subcategory name for single category

Tags: magento-2.1, category

I am trying to fetch current subcategory name of specific parent  category which id is  5 for example my category is Brand and subcategory is Brand1/Brand2/brand3 so i want fetch current subcategory category on product page .

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
          $parent_category = $current_category->getParentCategory();
          echo $current_category->getName();
          echo $parent_category->getName(); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get sub-category colletion for specific category, you need to used following code.

```
$categoryId = 5;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$current_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);

// Get Sub-Category For Current Categories

$subcategories = $parent_category->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($subcategories as $subcategorie) 
{
   echo $subcategorie->getName();
}
```

Comment: Dhiren Vasoya@ I am trying to print category name on product details page,I have brand and brand have many subcategory, when user click on brand subcategory then need to show only current subcategory.?

Comment: @sanjay you need product category? Check your question code, you are trying to get category from Registry, and it return when you are on category page.

Comment: Above code need on;y perform of specific category which ID is 5? can you help me

Comment: Can you clerify your requirement in detail. What you actualy want?

Comment: @sanjay are you looking to get sub-categories of main category where main category Id is 5? something like this?

Comment: Dhiren Vasoya@ my requirement is get category  of specific product category@for example when i click on books then books category name is show on page. but code is only run for books category and subcategory. not for other category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61539/discussion-between-sanjay-and-dhiren-vasoya).

Comment: @sanjay I update my answer according to your requirement. check now.